# understanding idea behind the p value

Tags: hypothesis-testing

today i would like to get a  deep  understanding of  meaning of p value  in hypothesis testing,  idea is that a lot of book say-if  p value is less then $\alpha$ reject null hypothesis, but if not dont reject, i  dont want to give  students such kind of memorization, instead i would like to explain them in detailed why we are rejecting,so let me explain my idea

we have  two type of errors  Type 1 and  Type 2 error

A type I error occurs if you reject the null hypothesis when it is true.

A type II error occurs if you do not reject the null hypothesis when it is false.

$\alpha$ controls probability of  A type I, so if $\alpha$ is 5%, that means that there is  $5$% percent  of  reject the null hypothesis when it is true.now  let us consider the following example

null hypothesis is that $\mu$=50 , while alternative hypothesis  is that $\mu$>50, we collected data,  we get sample mean 52 and we estimated p value which is 0.013, which means that probability of  getting test statistic  52  or more is 0.013 while null hypothesis is true, because it is less then alpha we are rejecting null hypothesis, but here is my question : what is the idea of rejecting? why we are rejecting? lets dont talk in terms of formulated laws, just in a simple manner , if null hypothesis is true(that means if  mean is 50) and probability of getting 52 or more is less then 5%, that means   we should not expect too much to that  sample mean will be different then  50 right? in other words, sample mean should give  the evidence of  50 right?probability of getting more then 50 is less then 5%, am i right?

Comment: any ideas?by the  we  last i have  posted several questions  on this site and i have not got answer, did i do something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Following your example, if you believe the population mean to be $50$ and you obtain a sample mean of $52$, the small p value is indicating that this value is a very unlikely occurrence and may be evidence that the mean is actually greater than $50$.

So on the basis of this sample alone, we are rejecting the null hypothesis that the mean is $50$.

Comment: which number is unlikely occurrence? 50?

Comment: if the population mean is 50 then the occurrence of 52, according to your p value, is unlikely

Comment: and which number is more likely to occur?because if  52 is   very unlikely to occur, that means that 50 may occur right?

Comment: all these values have low individual probabilities, but 52 is in the critical region, whereas 50 is not

Comment: still same language as  it is written in book, i need  different view, if probability of getting 52 or bigger is less then alpha, what does it mean in simplest words?